# How to run perl critic from a script with ProhibitExcessComplexity enabled?

Tags: perl, perl-critic

How do I run Perl critic from a script with `Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity` enabled ? I tried the following but it wasn't flagging complex 500+ line subroutines.
I do not have a `.perlcriticrc`(Neither do I want one to be there)

```
use Perl::Critic;

run_critic('temp.pl');
exit;

sub run_critic {
    my $file   = shift;
    my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(
        -severity => 5,
        -policy   => 'Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity',
        -verbose  => 5,
    );
    my @violations = $critic->critique($file);
    print @violations;
}
```

My `Perl::Critic` version is `1.116`

```
perl -MPerl::Critic -e 'print "$Perl::Critic::VERSION\n"'
1.116
```

Comment: `-policy` is not an option for `new` in the POD.

Comment: Use `-single-policy` or `-include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### View the loaded Policies

To view the policies that are actually loaded, use [`Perl::Critic->policies`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic#METHODS).

> #### policies()
>
> Returns a list containing references to all the Policy objects that have been loaded into this engine. Objects will be in the order that they were loaded.
>   If you view your policies, you can see it's not being added:

You will see your desired policy isn't added to the list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Perl::Critic;

run_critic($0);
exit;

sub run_critic {
    my $file   = shift;
    my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(
        -severity => 5,
        -policy   => 'Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity',
        -verbose  => 5,
    );
    print $critic->policies();      # View loaded Policies

    my @violations = $critic->critique($file);
    print @violations;
}
```

Outputs:

```
BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitSleepViaSelect
BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitStringyEval
BuiltinFunctions::RequireGlobFunction
ClassHierarchies::ProhibitOneArgBless
ControlStructures::ProhibitMutatingListFunctions
InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles
InputOutput::ProhibitInteractiveTest
InputOutput::ProhibitTwoArgOpen
InputOutput::RequireEncodingWithUTF8Layer
Modules::ProhibitEvilModules
Modules::RequireBarewordIncludes
Modules::RequireFilenameMatchesPackage
Subroutines::ProhibitExplicitReturnUndef       
Subroutines::ProhibitNestedSubs
Subroutines::ProhibitReturnSort
Subroutines::ProhibitSubroutinePrototypes
TestingAndDebugging::ProhibitNoStrict
TestingAndDebugging::RequireUseStrict
ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitLeadingZeros
Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations
Variables::RequireLexicalLoopIterators
```

#### Proper Configuration option: `-include`

The problem is that the [Constructor option](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic#CONSTRUCTOR) `-policy` does not exist.

Instead you want to use `-include`:

> **`-include`** is a reference to a list of string `@PATTERNS`. Policy modules that match at least one `m/$PATTERN/ixms` will always be loaded, irrespective of all other settings. For example:

Therefore fixing your constructor:

```
    my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(
        -severity => 5,
        -include  => 'Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity',
        -verbose  => 5,
    );
```

Outputs:

```
BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitSleepViaSelect
BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitStringyEval
BuiltinFunctions::RequireGlobFunction
ClassHierarchies::ProhibitOneArgBless
ControlStructures::ProhibitMutatingListFunctions
InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles
InputOutput::ProhibitInteractiveTest
InputOutput::ProhibitTwoArgOpen
InputOutput::RequireEncodingWithUTF8Layer
Modules::ProhibitEvilModules
Modules::RequireBarewordIncludes
Modules::RequireFilenameMatchesPackage
Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity           # <--- ta da
Subroutines::ProhibitExplicitReturnUndef
Subroutines::ProhibitNestedSubs
Subroutines::ProhibitReturnSort
Subroutines::ProhibitSubroutinePrototypes
TestingAndDebugging::ProhibitNoStrict
TestingAndDebugging::RequireUseStrict
ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitLeadingZeros
Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations
Variables::RequireLexicalLoopIterators
```

Comment: It seems like -severity is ignored with -include.  Do you see that behavior?

Comment: @toolic Ah, just found where this is described in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic#new): "Policy modules that match at least one `m/$PATTERN/ixms` will always be loaded, **irrespective of all other settings.** For example: `my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(-include => ['layout'] -severity => 4);` This would cause `Perl::Critic` to apply all the `CodeLayout::*` Policy modules even though they have a severity level that is less than 4." (emphasis added)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: ++ I saw that, too, but I stopped reading too soon.  So -severity is irrelevant w/ -include.  This answer should be updated with this info.

Answer (score 1):

`Subroutines::ProhibitExcessComplexity` has a severity of 3 (as seen from the source code), but you are using 5. This means you are only showing violations of severity=5. Set the `-severity` to 1, 2 or 3:

```
my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(-severity => 1);
```

Also note that `-policy` is not an option for `new` in the POD; it is ignored.

Comment: It works for me if I use either `-single-policy` or `-include` and `-severity => 5`.

Comment: (In other words, the issue with the OP's code was the `-policy` option, not `-severity`.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: My code works for me.  I'm using an older version (1.111), however.  It should depend on the severity.

Comment: Your code works for me, too; I wasn't saying it's wrong, just that the real cause of the OP's error was using the non-existent `-policy` option instead of `-single-policy` or `-include`. I agree that the severity *should* affect it, but it doesn't seem to in my tests (at least on v1.122).

Comment: -policy is ignored by new().  -foo is also ignored by new().  If I leave -policy in (which is not desirable), and I change the severity to 1, then it works.  Maybe it's TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: But you're also loading *all* policies (assuming the OP doesn't have a `.perlcriticrc` file, which is what they said in the comments earlier). Using `-include` only loads the specified policies, which seems to be what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Of course, on re-reading the question, they just say they want to enable the policy, not that they want to enable *only* that policy, so perhaps I'm interpreting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [`perlcritic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Critic/bin/perlcritic) utility instead. It can do nice things like colorize the output or send it to a pager for you. Then you can wrap it with a shell script, alias, or backticks, or a `system()` call or whatever you like.

```
# Analyze with just the ProhibitExcessComplexity policy
perlcritic --single-policy=ProhibitExcessComplexity FILES_OR_DIRECTORIES

# Analyze with all severity 5 policies, plus ExcessComplexity
perlcritic --severity=5 --include=ProhibitExcessComplexity FILES_OR_DIRECTORIES
```